# Use Jaydata with NTLM autentification OData Service

Tags: odata, ntlm, jaydata

Can I autorised by NTLM protocol if I use Jaydata? And how can I do this? I look into oDataProvider.js and see only Basic autentification possible.

if I try autorise as in examples http://jaydata.org/blog/super-easy-authentication-and-authorization-with-odata-server I always have 401 error.

Many thanks & best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NTLM auth if you use JayData on the client-side to consume OData services. In this case you have to authenticate your user in your application with your webserver (for example IIS) and JayData uses the same session.

Publishing OData services with JayData (odata-server npm module) with NTLM authentication isn't possible yet.